# How to make a 5-point perspective camera view?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera

Look at this painting, *The Courtyard* by Irvine Peacock:

[image]

As you can see, there is a sort of fish-eye effect here so that the lines curve, so that you can see more of the image. How can I recreate this effect?

Comment: I havent tried it with the blender camera but in real life you would use an extremely short focal length lens IE 12mm or 9mm. You maybe able to fake it using a Lattice.

Comment: In the camera settings switch from *Perspective* to *Panoramic*. It will work only on render.

Answer (score 8):

You may achieve it using ***Fisheye Equisolid*** type of the ***Panoramic*** camera (with some manual vertices tweaking).
[image]

Add a *camera* and position it verticaly as pictured below. Add a *plane* and place it in front of it. Add a background image (display axis type: *Camera*), decrease its opacity and push the *Front* button.
[image]

Set the render resolution so it is the same as image's resolution.
[image]

Enter the camera view (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num 0</kbd>) and rotate it along the Z axis to fit the plane to the reference. Extrude the plane until you you build the rough representation of the object from the picture.
[image]

Select the extruded object in *Object Mode* and give it a material (Emission e.g.). Also give it a ***Wireframe Modifier*** with some thickness.
[image]

In ***Cycles*** go to *Camera Data* header--> *Lens* panel and set the camera type to ***Panoramic (Fisheye Equisolid)***. Experiment with ***Lens*** and ***Field of View*** values. In this case I found *Lens*=14 and *FoV*=180 optimal.
[image]

Divide the *3d view* into two windows. Set the *Solid* viewport shading mode for the first and *Rendered* for the second one.
[image]

Snap the cursor to the origin point of the plane. Grab the camera and translate it along the Z axis. Next rotate it along the local Y axis (press <kbd>R</kbd>, then double tap <kbd>Y</kbd>) to fit the image as precisely as you can.
[image]

Controling two views at the same time you can now easily make the subdivisions to the mesh and model the details.
[image]

To make the model exactly fit the reference's perspective you may tweak some vertices. 
[image]
[image]

Here's the comparision between original and tweaked perspectives.
[image]